# Finite element error for second order ODE at nodes equal to zero

Tags: finite-element, convergence, elliptic-pde

I coded a finite element method with linear basis elements for the problem $$-u'' = f(x), x\in[0,1], u(0) = u(1) = 0$$ The nodes are uniformly spaced and I will denote them as $x_i$. I initially calculated the error of my method as $$\text{error} = \max_i |u(x_i) - \hat{u}(x_i)|$$
where $\hat{u}$ denotes the FEM solution. I kept getting approximately 0 as the error, and I'm thinking that's because the FEM solution interpolates the exact solution $u$ at the nodes $x_i$.

I then went back and got an approximation for $$\max_{x\in[0,1]} |u(x) - \hat{u}(x)|$$ and I got second-order convergence (as expected).

My question is does the FEM (with linear/quadratic/cubic piecewise basis functions) always give back an interpolation of the exact solution, and so should I expect an error of zero at the nodes?

Comment: What is the expression for $f(x)$?

Comment: I too have observed FEM yielding slightly better accuracy than in the interior of the elements.  It doesn't always happen, nor does it necessarily yield error within floating point precision when it does happen.  I think bill barth is right in that it is a special circumstance that occaisionally happens in numerical computation called 'superconvergence'.  I don't remember the precise reason ***why*** it happens.  It may have sonething to do with the function f that you chose.  What was f in this case?

Comment: I tried a few different functions for $f$. First was $f\equiv 2$, which has the exact solution of $u(x) = (1-x)x$. Then I tried $f(x) = -e^x (x^4 + 6x^3 + x^2 - 8x + 2)$, which has an exact solution of $u(x) = e^x (1-x)^2 x^2$. For both of them, the error was somewhere around $10^{-14}$.

Comment: Yes, for this problem, the solution is exact at the nodes provided your integrals in the weak formulation are exact. This is a nice assignment/exam question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this simple elliptic PDE, the finite-element approximation is indeed exact at the nodes (i.e., coincides with the true solution); this is usually called *superconvergence (at the nodes)*.

Since it's such a nice homework problem, instead of the (simple) proof, here's a hint: Use the weak formulation with a hat function centered on $x_i$ as a test function, Galerkin orthogonality, and partial integration.

Comment: @ChristianClason, I don't have time to dig up the books necessary. Feel free to edit or add your own answer that is better or doesn't make the robots sad.

Comment: @ChristianClason, I that's a great edit, but I think you only left me with two definite articles. Maybe it'd be better in your own name?

Comment: @ChristianClason, done. Maybe someone else will give the full proof as you outlined.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the same proof I had in mind, and I'm having a go at it right now.

Comment: I've mostly read things on 
Stackexchange and haven't posted much, so I'm not sure what I should do here. I wrote a proof, so should I post it as an answer and get feedback? Or should I edit my post?

Comment: @animal_magic, you're allowed to provide answers to your own questions. It's encouraged, especially if it's good quality. The community wiki style posts allow several members to work together on an answer without anyone getting the reputation bonus. If you want to edit this one to extend it, feel free, or post yours separately.

Comment: @animal_magic It's allowed (and encouraged) but not required -- if the answer helped you sufficiently to solve your problem, you can also just accept it and move on.

Comment: I'll just leave the answer as is. I think it's a nice exercise and it gets you most of the way there. I'll just say that the place to start is to look at the variational formulation of the problem. To be more specific, look at $(u', \phi_i') = (f,\phi_i)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product, $u$ is the exact solution, and $\phi_i$ is a hat function centered at $x_i$. Then just relate that to the linear system we solve to get the weights for $\hat{u}$. Hopefully that's not too cryptic.

Comment: I should have said $\tilde{u}$ instead of $u$ in my comment, where $\tilde{u}$ is the linear interpolation of the exact solution $u$.